# How To update Active Reports 16 RDLX to handle images from previous version

Tags: c#, activereports

I've recently started the upgrade from ActiveReports 15 to 16, and I have a project with thousands of AR rdlx reports templates. Most of those templates have either background images for the whole report, or have header images for branding logos.

In every single report I've opened so far, the images are broken. they are rendering in the same physical dimensions, but the image is "zoomed in" about 4x. In looking into the images, and re-creating a few of them in Photoshop from the original, I noticed that the old images were anywhere from 150 to 300 DPI, and when creating the new image, I made it 72 dpi. v16 handles the new image perfectly, but doesn't deal well with the older, higher dpi, images.

I don't have the time to re-generate, and then re-embed, thousands of images in thousands of report templates (which is one guaranteed fix). Is there a setting that will make v16 recognize and correctly render the images that v15 handled?